# Poor FTP Performance due to delayed Ack : Solutions exist for Android?

Tags: android, performance, ftp, latency, delay

i have a Problem using FTP connection on Android 2.2 devices.

My app uses AndFTP via intent and loads data from a FTP Server connected via Wifi to the handset.

The FTP downloadspeed is only 7kByte/s.

I had the same speed on my Windows XP Notebook, then i changed the delayed acknowledge setting. So now my Notebook reaches 300kbyte/s but i dont know how to adjust the Settings in Android / Linux based OS Systems.

Does anyone know about this latency problems?

Best regards, 
Rotesmofa

Edit: now i finaly found the SocketOptions for my problem but how to set no_delay? 
Can i set this in my App or do i have to set it on every device with a terminal tool?
Link to the SocketDescription: [link text](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/SocketOptions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so for anyone which encounters the same problem look at the specific solutions for your platform for delayed acknowledges. Some more explanations can be found here http://www.stuartcheshire.org/papers/NagleDelayedAck/

Use a specific fix and the speed will return to normal.

Best regards, 
Rotesmofa